# How wildcarding effect recipe lookup process in yocto?

Tags: yocto, recipe

I have two recipe, One of them is **"gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend"** and its in **meta-petalinux** layer and the other recipe's name is **"gstreamer1.0_1.16.1.bb"** and its in **meta** layer.

How wildcarding effects recipe lookup in build process ?
Could you please explain which recipe selected when priority of spesified layers are same, and which recipe selected when priority of spesified layers are different ?

Thanks.

Comment: Only one of them is a recipe: the other one is an append to that recipe. I don't think layer priorities  really come in to play here.

Answer (score 1):

`gstreamer1.0_1.16.1.bbappend` will be applied on `gstreamer1.0_1.16.1.bb` only.

`gstreamer1.0_%.bbappend` will be applied on anything that matches the pattern: `gstreamer1.0_` + `whatever (e.g. version)` + `.bb`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I totaly misunderstand the concept. I realized the difference between .bbappend and .bb files with your help.